# Localhost Not Responding

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

I Just Install Wamp Server and All are Ok. But when i Write localhost on my Browser it open but when i Click my Folder like Wordpress or Joomla it Give this Error

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I really dont know What to Do now and i have too Much Problem

Comment: Follow an "how to install wordpress" tutorial. https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

Comment: I Just Write Wordpress for Demo . I have This Problem on All Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation of joomla (doc of 2.5) : your site will be accessed at yoursite.com/Joomla instead of yoursite.com.

With wordpress

1 - Delete .htaccess and keep htaccess.txt.

2 - Global Configuration/SEO Settings, value of  Search Engine Friend URLs => No